# Multiple select menu box with hidden form field

Tags: jquery

I am building a simple 'sign-up' form to purchase licenses. If you wish to acquire more than 1 license a 'hidden' form field appears so you can enter precise number required. Please see ***User License** on the following 
 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh3f94gu/19/).

```
$("#order_users").change(function ()
```

I am trying to add something similar to specify weather it is a 'personal' or business' account. If its a 'business' account one would enter a business name in the box that appears. I have tried numerous attempts to get a second function working correctly for this purpose. Different function names, different 'values' for val etc etc

```
$("#account_type").change(function (accountChange) 
var val2 = $(this).val2(); etc etc
```

The html for the second function can be seen on the fiddle, but I can't get it working in tandem with the original jquery function. Can someone please help?

Comment: In your Fiddle `$(..).validate() is not a function` error is being thrown and is stopping any code after that from executing. Also, `.val2()` is not a valid jQuery function. Simply use `.val()` to either get or set `.val('new-val')` the value of an input.

Comment: The original function uses the JQuery validator plugin...without that bottom bit of code neither work. I thought the 'val' var. iterates through the first funcion/variable it finds..? Can you please update the fiddle using the commented out code above so both fire on same page?

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh3f94gu/24/) if you want to use a plugin on jsFiddle you need to include a link to the source in the Resources panel.

Comment: That's excellent - thank you very much!